# Prevent firefox from highlighting "invalid" (html5) checkboxes at form first load

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, webshim

I'm using html5 validations for a form, using [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html) (a polyfill solution).
Webshim made a validation for group checkboxes- that you must check at least one of the group: ([here](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#Custom-addValidators.), search for **data-grouprequired**)

I made an improved validation that also includes a minimum and a maximum boxes that must be checked.

Both work (here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq06yrgL/3/) with both) BUT in **firefox** (not chrome nor ie11) after page first loads, the "invalid" checkboxes are **already** highlighted in red, as seen in given fiddle- only with firefox.

So my question is: How to I prevent Firefox from highlighting those "invalid" as the page loads? (User didn't even have a chance to fill those fields yet)

I created this fiddle so you can easily try things: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq06yrgL/3/)

Thank you.

- I added the Webshim example to show that the "problem" (different behavior) is not so much with my code as it is with firefox (picture).

[image]

Here is the code: 
html:

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>checkboxes with webshim groupRequired:</label>
        <div id="foo5">
            <input name="b" type="checkbox" data-grouprequired="" />
            <input name="b" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="b" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="b" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>checkboxes with my custom min/max (min:2, max:3) :</label>
        <div id="foo">
            <input id="cb1" class="cb" name="a" data-max="3" data-min="2" type="checkbox" />
            <input id="cb2" class="cb" name="a" data-max="3" data-min="2" type="checkbox" />
            <input id="cb3" class="cb" name="a" data-max="3" data-min="2" type="checkbox" />
            <input id="cb4" class="cb" name="a" data-max="3" data-min="2" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="foo3" type="text" id="name" required="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
 //webshim.setOptions
 webshim.setOptions("forms", {
     lazyCustomMessages: true,
     replaceValidationUI: true,
     customDatalist: "auto",
     addValidators: true

 });
 //request the features you need:
 webshim.polyfill('forms');

 $(function () {
     // use all implemented API-features on DOM-ready
     //webshim.activeLang(); //returns current set language

     webshim.activeLang('en'); //set locale to en

     i3 = 0;
     i4 = 0;
     first_arr = {};
     $('.cb').each(function (index, wrap) {
         first_arr[$(this).attr('id')] = ++i3;
         $(this).on('validatevalue', function (e, extra) {
             //failed fix attempt:
             if (false && first_arr[$(this).attr('id')] > 0) {
                 first_arr[$(this).attr('id')] = --i4;
                 return;
             }//end of failed fix attempt
             var elem = e.currentTarget;
             var min = $(e.currentTarget).data('min');
             var max = $(e.currentTarget).data('max');
             var total = $(elem).parents('#foo').find('input:checked').length;

             if (min && min > 0 && max && max > 0 && (total > max || total < min)) {
                 return 'Must select between ' + min + ' to ' + max;
             }
             if (min && min > 0 && total < min) {
                 return "can't select less than " + min;
             }
             if (max && max > 0 && total > max) {
                 return "can't select more than " + max;
             }
             $('.cb').not($(elem)).each(function () {
                 $(this).setCustomValidity("");
             });
         });
     });
 });
```

I'll also add how Webshim did their own custom, checkbox grouprequired validation, [their github file](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/49514758ead06779ef8e01e6f50704c512bc3dfd/src/shims/form-validators.js):

```
addCustomValidityRule('grouprequired', function(elem, val, data){
        var form, name;
        if(!('grouprequired' in data) || elem.type !== 'checkbox' || !(name = elem.name)){return;}

        if(!data.grouprequired.checkboxes){
            data.grouprequired = {};
            data.grouprequired.checkboxes = $( ((form = $.prop(elem, 'form')) && form[name]) || document.getElementsByName(name)).filter('[type="checkbox"]');
            data.grouprequired.checkboxes
                .off('click.groupRequired')
                .on('click.groupRequired', function(){
                    if((data.customMismatchedRule == 'grouprequired') == this.checked){
                        $(elem).trigger('updatevalidation.webshims');
                    }
                })
            ;

            data.grouprequired.checkboxes.not(elem).removeData('grouprequired');
        }

        return !(data.grouprequired.checkboxes.filter(':checked:enabled')[0]);
    }, 'Please check one of these checkboxes.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`input[type='checkbox']:invalid {
box-shadow: none !important;
}`

See:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/11/firefox-4-html5-forms/

Do a find on the page for ":invalid"

You may also need:

`input[type='checkbox']:required {
box-shadow: none !important;
}`